# Problem sending a post 'excerpt is not defined in 'post'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hygraph

Answer: I figured it out. The follow-along is old and GraphQL API had an update. I had to go to their API Playground and re-do the code.

I am making a blog with Nextjs using hygraph.com as the back end. I was trying to get it to where you can see the posts when you click, and it suddenly stopped working on me. If you do need it, here is my entire code: https://github.com/DeviousWings/blog-app

I am using this follow-along for the program:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYv55DhgTuA
My mess-up seems to be at the 1:46:40 mark.

If you need more information, let me know, and I will put an "edit" in front.

Here is the error message:

```
Server Error
Error: [line: 1] field 'excerpt' is not defined in 'Post':
 {"response":{"errors":[{"message":
"[line: 1] field 'excerpt' is not defined in 'Post'"}],
"data":null,"extensions":"requestId":"clgir0yw21ztz0blki9cm5z9o"},
"status":400,"headers":{}},"request":

query GetPostDetails($slug : String!) {
    post(where: {slug: $slug}) {

      author{
        name
        bio
        photo {
          url
        }
      }
      createdAt
      slug
      title
      excerpt
      featuredImage {
        url
      }
      categories {
        name
        slug
      }
      content {
        raw
      }
    }
  }
`;
 ",
"variables":{"slug":"space-cockpit"}}}
```

Here is the source of the mess up:

```
services\index.js (109:17) @ async getPostDetails

  107 | 
  108 | 
> 109 | const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { slug });
      |               ^
  110 | 
  111 | return result.post;
  112 | };
```

Here is the entire code where the source is located (blog-app\services\index.js):

```
import { request, gql } from "graphql-request";

const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT;

export const getPosts = async () => {
    const query = gql
    `query MyQuery {
      postsConnection {
        edges {
          node {
            author {
              bio
              name
              id
              photo {
                url
              }
            }
            createdAt
            slug
            title
            exerpt
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
            categories {
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    `;

    const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query)

    return result.postsConnection.edges;
};

export const getCategories = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetGategories {
        categories {
          name
          slug
        }
    }
  `;
  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

  return result.categories;
  }
export const getRecentPosts = async () => {
  const query = gql `
  query GetPostDetails() {
    posts(
      orderBy: createdAt_ASC
      last: 3
      ) {
        title
        featuredImage {
          url
        }
        createdAt
        slug
      }
  }
  `

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query)

  return result.posts;
};

export const getPostDetails = async (slug) => {
  const query = gql`
  query GetPostDetails($slug : String!) {
    post(where: {slug: $slug}) {

      author{
        name
        bio
        photo {
          url
        }
      }
      createdAt
      slug
      title
      excerpt
      featuredImage {
        url
      }
      categories {
        name
        slug
      }
      content {
        raw
      }
    }
  }
`;

  

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { slug });

  return result.post;
};

export const getSimilarPosts = async (categories, slug) => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetPostDetails($slug: String!, $categories: [String!]) {
      posts(
        where: {slug_not: $slug, AND: {categories_some: {slug_in: $categories}}}
        last: 3
      ) {
        title
        featuredImage {
          url
        }
        createdAt
        slug
      }
    }
  `;
  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { slug, categories });

  return result.posts;
};
```

My Models:

[CommentModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0xMH.jpg)

[Post Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrVk1.jpg)

I am not good at debugging but my console.log did not pick up anything.

Comment: Figured it out. The follow-along is old and GraphQL API had an update. I had to go to their API Playground and re-do the code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The follow-along is old and GraphQL API had an update. I had to go to their API Playground and re-do the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).